# Object Tap Patch - Spark AR Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

Day 1 of my spark AR app, I can't seem to get Object Tap working. Steps followed are

**Req:** On menu tap, I want one object to be visible.

1. I have a plane Object with menu texture. so this is my producer object. Dragged it to patch editor and in scene right clicked object and clicked create patch.
2. Selected a object tap patch which received input from step1.
3. Selected object to change from scene; and clicked on radio icon next visible property so now this is my consumer appeared on patch editor.
4. Now connected output from step 2 to step3 input.

**Current Output:**  When I mirror this on device on tap of menu(leadership), object(playback_screen) does not get visible. Any idea or pointers will be highly appreciated.

[image: Patch Editor Screenshot]

Comment: found the bug; you can not have tap event registered on and element in scripting as well as on patch editor

Comment: You have to be careful with ui, cuz facebook really don't custom stuff! Your effect could be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

From object tap give input to counter (search counter in patch editor) then set count as per your requirement...

then take Equals Exactly block in patch editor set value in it and finally give input to visibility node from Equals Exactly block...[See this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h80iA.png)